# Is it true that irrational roots of rational polynomial comes in pairs? How to prove this? If not give an example please.

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots, irrational-numbers

I have no information about this. In some places it is written true in some places it is written false. I am sure that if polynomial is quadratic then it is true. But what if not a quadratic polynomial? please help me.

Comment: What about $x^3-2$?

Comment: In general they will come in orbits under permutation by a finite group, but these orbits need not be pairs.

Comment: What does it mean to "come in pairs" ? (Complex roots come in *conjugate* pairs.)

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^3-3x=\frac12\iff \cos3\theta=\cos\frac\pi3$$
 and there are three irrational solutions

$$\cos\frac\pi9,\cos\frac{7\pi}9,\cos\frac{15\pi}9.$$